# Android spinner shows both an arrow and the select circle?

Tags: android, user-interface

I am curious if I am just choosing something incorrectly here.  I want to use the standard drop down selection for spinners, however when it displays on the screen, it shows both the drop down arrow, and the circle from the item selected.  I've included a screenshot since this probably doesn't make sense.  Any idea how to make the circle go away once the spinner item is selected?

[image]

Comment: Can u show ur part of code where u have setadapter for spinner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you must have used your **textview resource** in **ArrayAdapter as android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item.**

Please changed it to this **android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainEntryActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item ,arlstName);
        spinnerName.setAdapter(adpt);
        adpt.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Please change the above code to this if you have done like above

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainEntryActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item ,arlstName);
            spinnerName.setAdapter(adpt);
            adpt.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Hope it helps